# Python: Live update of lists and dictionaries?

Tags: python, tkinter

Python 3.6

Hello all, I can't seem to figure out how to get my GUI interface to live update a label. This label contains information from a list and this list is manipulated via buttons. However the number does not update! I've have tried using after() but after many failed attempts I don't understand how to get it to work.

Would I need to put it into a function that would then update my GUI? Or how else could I achieve this? I am still learning to program and very new to it. Any other tips are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

My label:

```
stock5 = Label(Stockframe, font=('Agency FB',20), text=(stock['Intel i7-
7770T QUAN'][0]))
stock5.grid(row=0, column=5)
```

My list:

```
{'Intel i7-7770T QUAN' : [3] }
```

I have tried this but to no success:

```
def updater():

     after(1000, updater)

     updater()
```

I am most probably misunderstanding how to use after()! Thank you!

Comment: `updater` doesn't do anything but call itself; what were you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `updater` function needs to actually update the label.

Assuming that `stock5` and `stock` are global variables, and assuming that you are somehow updating `stock` on a regular basis, something like this would work:

```
def updater():
    new_value = stock['Intel i7-7770T QUAN'][0]
    stock5.configure(text=new_value)
    after(1000, updater)
```